# How can I make a simple column of buttons down the west Jpanel (itempanel)?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout

I have added one `JButton` but it just becomes the same size as the `JPanel`. Any other `JButtons` added do not show up. 
I have tried numerous layout managers but they just either give me errors or place the buttons in extremely incorrect positions. 
Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class FurnitureShop extends JFrame {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new FurnitureShop().setVisible(true);
}

private FurnitureShop() {
    setSize(800, 600);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JPanel contentpanel  = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    contentpanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (800, 100));
    contentpanel.setBackground(Color.blue);

    JPanel footerpanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
      footerpanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (800, 100));
      footerpanel.setBackground(Color.cyan);


    JPanel headerpanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
      headerpanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (400, 200));
      headerpanel.setBackground(Color.black);


    JPanel itempanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
      itempanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (400, 200));
      itempanel.setBackground(Color.green);


      add(contentpanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      add(footerpanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      add(headerpanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
      add(itempanel, BorderLayout.WEST);

    JButton button = new JButton();
      button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (20, 20));
      //button.setLocation(20,20);
      button.setVisible(true);

  itempanel.add(button);
```

Comment: "I have tried numerous layout managers but they just either give me errors or place the buttons in extremely incorrect positions." What managers have you tried? What errors have you gotten? Do you have any screenshots of how they were incorrectly placed?

Comment: `"I have tried numerous layout managers but they just either give me errors or place the buttons in extremely incorrect positions."` -- tells us nothing that can help us understand what you're doing wrong. The solution is to use a decent combination of layout managers, so you're on the right track. Keep reading the tutorials because if you understand how to use them, you will know what to do.

Comment: Hint: GridLayout using JPanel holding your buttons placed in a BorderLayout using JPanel. Again, please read the layout manager tutorial -- it's all there!

Answer (score 3):

My first thought was to use `GridBagLayout` and while this would work, I was wondering if there might be an easier way.

This uses a `JPanel` with a `BorderLayout` as the primary container (added to the `EAST` position of the frame).  Onto this at the `NORTH` position is placed a `JPanel` with a `GridLayout` configured to use a single column

This is known as compound layouts.  It allows you to combine the functionality of a series of layout managers to meet your needs.  It's not very common that a single layout manager will meet every requirement you have and been able to separate the responsibility is a very powerful concept that allows you to focus in the individual requirements

Take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details.

[image: Buttons]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class ButtonColumns {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ButtonColumns();
    }

    public ButtonColumns() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                try {
                    JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("\path\to\images"))));

                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                    frame.add(label);

                    JPanel buttons = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
                    for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
                        buttons.add(new JButton(String.valueOf(index)));
                    }

                    JPanel right = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                    right.add(buttons, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                    frame.add(right, BorderLayout.EAST);

                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException exp) {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Booo! You always beat me. As a :P The OP said in the west +1 always.

Comment: @peeskillet Hay, I'm not going to do EVERYTHING for them ;)